# What is the status of water used for Kashering?

Tags: water, kashering-kosherization

If one kashers a pot by [boiling](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5455) water in it (and throwing rocks in so it overflows) or kashers silverware IN a pot, what is the status of the water afterwards? [I see that water can acquire some different [status](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Waters_Fit_for_Netilat_Yadayim) after certain uses, but I don't know if kashering is one of those situations]

Is the water totally useful or has it, by effecting a kosher status after touching the non-kosher surfaces, somehow taken the non-kosherness (if that's a thing) away so it shouldn't then be used? Is water constantly "self-kashering"?

L'ma'aseh, if I took my pork pot, wash it, wait a few days, then boil water and rocks in it, and, as it is boiling, throw some eggs in or some soup makings? Or should I dump the water and start fresh with a clean pot?

Comment: The custom is to rinse vessels in cold water after kashering (OC 452:7). So in the case of your pork pot you would just dump it out when rinsing it

Comment: So I dump the water into another pot and use it there to make eggs? Is the custom to rinse because of a concern over the water?

Answer (score 2):

### I just received this as one of the Halacha Yomit entries from Dirshu (I added the italics):

A person may kasher, in a kosher pot, a utensil that absorbed forbidden flavors, provided that the amount of water contained in the pot is sixty times the total area, of the surfaces and the thickness of the surfaces, of the utensil. After the pot is used for koshering, it is permitted to be used for other cooking needs, since the forbidden flavors are nullified in the water. Nonetheless, *the water which was used to kasher should not be used again. Some Achronim explain that if one were to reuse this water, it would appear as if he is intentionally nullifying the forbidden flavor in the water, which would be forbidden. Disposing of the water is a clear indication that the purpose of the hagalah was to remove the forbidden flavors. The Poskim disagree if the water may be used, after it cools down, to wash dishes.*

[משנ"ב תנב, יג; ביאורים ומוספים דרשו, 15]

Answer (score 1):

The Taz in Siman 95 sif katan 10 discussing a different case explains the Ram"a which says: "we treat the water as issur, le'chatchilla", says that reason is because water is not considered something important. 
Based on that I think that even when a dish a becomes kosher again the water has to be thrown out.
Also check the pri magadim there.

Comment: could I let the water cool (in the case of a case of a pot full of cutlery) and then reuse it for other cutlery after heating it up again? What is the nature of the issur?

Comment: no sure. because it depends on a few factors of why you are kashering and how much issur is in the pot walls. also keep in mind that in your question the issur is now technically pagum... also in general  the contents of a pot aren't 60 x the walls of the pot so you can't use that to say that the issur is nullified in the water unless you know the amount of issur that there was initially absorbed in the pot...  you get my drift...